# Pie Chart showing "other" when it should show data

Tags: google-visualization

I have implemented Google Pie Chart.
All works perfectly but when i try to add data less than 10 it do not plot on chart instead of that it add a new entry under legend named - "Other"

My Script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Task', 'Age Difference'],
['>10',        15],
['10-15',      <?php echo $agecnt2;?>],
['16-20',      <?php echo $agecnt3;?>],
['21-25',      <?php echo $agecnt4;?>],
['26-30',      <?php echo $agecnt5;?>],
['31-35',      <?php echo $agecnt6;?>],
['36-40',      <?php echo $agecnt7;?>],
['41-45',      <?php echo $agecnt8;?>],
['46-50',      <?php echo $agecnt9;?>],
['51-55',      <?php echo $agecnt10;?>],
['56-60',      <?php echo $agecnt11;?>],
['61-65',      <?php echo $agecnt12;?>],
['66-70',      <?php echo $agecnt13;?>],
['71-75',      <?php echo $agecnt14;?>],
['76-80',      <?php echo $agecnt15;?>],
['>80',        <?php echo $agecnt16;?>]
]);

var options = {
  title: 'Age Difference'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Google Pie chart groups all "small" slices into an "Other" group. As a default, any group that would have a default smaller than 1/2degree is grouped into the "Other" section. You can modify the `sliceVisibilityThreshold` (described [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)) to minimize/eliminate this effect.

Comment: if you dont't want it to show at all, set it to 0 ie

`sliceVisibilityThreshold: 2`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue - just that the numbers were actually not too much different.

The datatable rendered perfectly as ColumnChart, but failed to show slices as PieChart.

What resolved the issue for me was casting the values in php to integer with `intval()`.

Apparently the ColumnChart visualization is forgiving, while the PieChart is not when it comes to values other than integers.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that my php code was still a string because of echo. 
So i did this:

```
parseInt("<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>")
```

and it worked.